# ¿Cómo borrar elementos de una lista en jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo que realizar una lista que por cada tarea añadida genere un botón borrar para eliminarla, el caso es que no consigo hacer que el botón diferencie un elemento de otro. He intentado buscarlas por nombre pero no se como identificar a que botón se le ha dado el `click` para saber su nombre. Había pensado en poner diferentes `ids` a cada botón pero no se como realizar esa idea. Muchas gracias!!

Adjunto codigo:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="formulario">
    <form>
        <label>Tarea</label>
        <input type="text" id="tarea" name="nombre">
        <br>
        <label>Prioridad</label>
        <select name="prioridad" id="prioridad">
            <option value="alta">Alta</option>
            <option value="media">Media</option>
            <option value="baja">Baja</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label>Tipo</label>
        <input type="radio" id="trabajo" name="tipo" value="Trabajo">Trabajo   
        <input type="radio" id="personal" name="tipo" value="Personal">Personal
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" id="botonAnadir" value="Add">

    </form>

</div>
<div id="listadoTareas">
    <h2>Listado de Tareas:</h2>
    <ul id="listaTareas"></ul>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var tareas=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lista"));
        if(tareas!=null){
            for(var i=0; i<tareas.length;i++){
                $('#listaTareas').append('<li>'+tareas[i].tarea+" - "+tareas[i].prioridad+" - "+tareas[i].tipo+ ' <input type="button" id="clearStorage" value="Borrar Datos">'+ '</li>');
            }
        }
    });

    $('#botonAnadir').on('click', function(){
            var aux=0;
            var tareas=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lista"));
            if(tareas==null){
                tareas=[];
            }

            var tarea=$('#tarea').val();
            var prioridad=$('#prioridad').val();
            var tipo=$('input:radio[name=tipo]:checked').val()
            var lista={
                "tarea": tarea,
                "prioridad": prioridad,
                "tipo": tipo
            }
            aux=buscarNombre(tarea, tareas);
            if(aux===1){
                alert("Ya tiene introducida la tarea");
            }
            else{
                tareas.push(lista);
                localStorage.setItem("lista", JSON.stringify(tareas));
                $('#listaTareas').append('<li>'+lista.tarea+" - "+lista.prioridad+" - "+lista.tipo+  '<input type="button" class="borrar" value="Borrar Datos"> '+ '</li>');
            }
    });

    $(document).on('click','.borrar', function(){
                   localStorage.removeItem("lista");


    });

    function buscarNombre(tarea, tareas){
        var aux=0;
        for(var i=0;i<tareas.length;i++){
                if(tareas[i].tarea===tarea){
                    aux=1;
                }
        }
        return aux;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando `$(this)` dentro de tu evento `click` indicas que el botón al que diste `click` sea el que accionara cualquier evento que tu necesites, en este caso, obtendremos el padre de ese botón que su caso sería el `<li>`, y se lo asignaremos a una variable, para después eliminarlo con el evento `remove();`

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="formulario">
    <form>
        <label>Tarea</label>
        <input type="text" id="tarea" name="nombre">
        <br>
        <label>Prioridad</label>
        <select name="prioridad" id="prioridad">
            <option value="alta">Alta</option>
            <option value="media">Media</option>
            <option value="baja">Baja</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label>Tipo</label>
        <input type="radio" id="trabajo" name="tipo" value="Trabajo">Trabajo   
        <input type="radio" id="personal" name="tipo" value="Personal">Personal
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" id="botonAnadir" value="Add">

    </form>

</div>
<div id="listadoTareas">
    <h2>Listado de Tareas:</h2>
    <ul id="listaTareas"></ul>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var tareas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lista"));
    if (tareas != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tareas.length; i++) {
            $('#listaTareas').append('<li class="'+tareas[i].tarea+'">' + tareas[i].tarea + " - " + tareas[i].prioridad + " - " + tareas[i].tipo + ' <input type="button" class="borrar" id="clearStorage" value="Borrar Datos">' + '</li>');
        }
    }
});

$('#botonAnadir').on('click', function() {
    var aux = 0;
    var tareas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lista"));
    if (tareas == null) {
        tareas = [];
    }

    var tarea = $('#tarea').val();
    var prioridad = $('#prioridad').val();
    var tipo = $('input:radio[name=tipo]:checked').val()
    var lista = {
        "tarea": tarea,
        "prioridad": prioridad,
        "tipo": tipo
    }
    aux = buscarNombre(tarea, tareas);
    if (aux === 1) {
        alert("Ya tiene introducida la tarea");
    } else {
        tareas.push(lista);
        localStorage.setItem("lista", JSON.stringify(tareas));
        $('#listaTareas').append('<li class="'+lista.tarea+'">' + lista.tarea + " - " + lista.prioridad + " - " + lista.tipo + '<input type="button" class="borrar" class="borrar" value="Borrar Datos"> ' + '</li>');
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.borrar', function() {
    var li = $(this)[0].parentNode;
    li.remove();
    var removeItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lista"));
    for (var i =0; i< removeItem.length; i++) {
    removeItem = $.grep(removeItem, function(n) {
    return n.tarea !== li.className;
});    

}
localStorage.setItem("lista", JSON.stringify(removeItem));



});

function buscarNombre(tarea, tareas) {
    var aux = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < tareas.length; i++) {
        if (tareas[i].tarea === tarea) {
            aux = 1;
        }
    }
    return aux;
}
 </script>
```

**UPDATE**

El `$(this)`, obtiene el objeto en este caso es el botón, pero obtiene todos sus elementos, pero el `$(this)[0]`, obtiene el elemento DOM del botón, y con el podemos obtener el `parentNode`.

Con este cambio ya puedes eliminar efectivamente el elemento del `localStorage`, lo que se hizo fue asignarle un identificador a cada `<li>`, y ya en base a ese identificador ir eliminando el elemento del `localStorage` que coincidiera con este identificador, noté que el elemento tarea solo se puede usar 1 vez, por lo tanto lo tome como un identificador, prueba el código y me comentas si te funciono.

Espero y sea lo que necesitas.

Comment: Una pregunta, a que se debe cuando pones $(this)[0].parentNode; el [0] porque se ha de poner? Y creo que no es lo que necesito, debido a que en el codigo para eliminar algo deberia elminarse de localStorage, habria alguna manera de obtener el nombre de la tarea del localStorage?

Comment: Modifiqué mi respuesta @GuillermoFuentes